# Agrupamento por diversas variáveis

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando na base abaixo, e preciso agrupar a variável close, agrupando o último dia de cada semana, por mês e ano, a base que estou trabalhando tem dados de 2005 a 2017, abaixo estou apenas deixando uma amostra.

```
date        close   year   month  day    quarter      week
2016-12-23   961    2016    12    23      4        51
2016-12-22   928    2016    12    22      4        51
2016-12-21   926    2016    12    21      4        51
2016-12-20   914    2016    12    20      4        51
2016-12-19   927    2016    12    19      4        51
2016-12-16   946    2016    12    16      4        50
2016-12-15   966    2016    12    15      4        50
2016-12-14   1003   2016    12    14      4        50
2016-12-13   1052   2016    12    13      4        50
2016-12-12   1069   2016    12    12      4        50
2016-12-23   934    2017    12    23      4        51
2016-12-22   928    2017    12    22      4        51
2016-12-21   926    2017    12    21      4        51
2016-12-20   914    2017    12    20      4        51
2016-12-19   927    2017    12    19      4        51
2016-12-16   933    2017    12    16      4        50
2016-12-15   966    2017    12    15      4        50
2016-12-14   1003   2017    12    14      4        50
2016-12-13   1052   2017    12    13      4        50
2016-12-12   1069   2017    12    12      4        50
```

Agrupamento deve ficar assim:

```
date       close    year    month     day     quarter   week
2016-12-23  961     2016      12      23       4         51
2016-12-16  946     2016      12      16       4         50
2017-12-23  934     2017      12      23       4         51
2017-12-16  933     2017      12      16       4         50
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: O que já tentou?

Comment: Tentei o código abaixo, mas ele não da certo, pois pega o last do dia, e eu quero a última data de cada semana, casteando por mês e ano.

df_bdiy = df_bdiy.groupby(['day','week','month','year'])['close'].last().reset_index()

Comment: Edite a pergunta pressionando o botão [edit] e apense o código de sua tentativa a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui o código abaixo:

```
df = df.sort_values(['year', 'month','quarter', 'week' , 'day']).drop_duplicates(['year', 'month','quarter', 'week'] , keep ='last')
```